# update listview with asyncTask

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I'm trying to download some data from yahoo finance and display them on screen with a listview.
I collect data well, my problem is to update the listview and delete data
Antique array.

here I leave my code:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

static List<String[]> datos = new ArrayList<String[]>();
static ListView lv;
static ArrayList nombres = new ArrayList();
static ArrayList valores = new ArrayList();

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    messageList(v);

    return v;
}

private void messageList(View v) {
    adapter adapter = new adapter(getActivity(), null);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, valores);
    new MyLongTask().execute(adaptador);

    for (int i = 0; i < datos.size(); i++) {
        for (int e = 0; e < 4; e++) {
            nombres.add(datos.get(i)[e]);
        }
    }
    datos.clear();
    valores = nombres;
    System.out.println(valores);

    lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv.setAdapter(adaptador);

}

static class MyLongTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayAdapter<String>, Void, Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute(ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador) {
        // Avísele al usuario que estamos trabajando
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(ArrayAdapter<String>... params) {
        System.out.println("entra en el hilo");
        datos.clear();
        String next[] = {};
        List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(
                    "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL+GOOG+MSFT&f=nab2b3");
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(in);
            for (;;) {
                next = reader.readNext();
                if (next != null) {
                    list.add(next);

                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            datos = list;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);// 2000 es 2 segundos
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("sale del hilo");

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador) {
        adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
        System.out.println("onpostexecute");
        new MyLongTask().execute();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

static List<String[]> datos = new ArrayList<String[]>();
static ListView lv;
static ArrayList nombres = new ArrayList();
static ArrayList valores = new ArrayList();
ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
messageList(v);

return v;
}

private void messageList(View v) {
adapter adapter = new adapter(getActivity(), null);//what is this???
adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, valores);
new MyLongTask().execute(adaptador);

for (int i = 0; i < datos.size(); i++) {
    for (int e = 0; e < 4; e++) {
        nombres.add(datos.get(i)[e]);
    }
}
datos.clear();
valores = nombres;
System.out.println(valores);

lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
lv.setAdapter(adaptador);

}

static class MyLongTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String[]>> {

protected void onPreExecute(ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador) {
    // Avísele al usuario que estamos trabajando
}

@Override
protected List<String[]> doInBackground(String... params) {
    System.out.println("entra en el hilo");
    datos.clear();
    String next[] = {};
    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    try {
        URL url = new URL(
                "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL+GOOG+MSFT&f=nab2b3");
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(in);
        for (;;) {
            next = reader.readNext();
            if (next != null) {
                list.add(next);

            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        datos = list;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(200);// 2000 es 2 segundos
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("sale del hilo");

    return list;
}

protected void onPostExecute(List<String[]> list) {
    adaptador.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        adaptador.add(/*add each item*/);
    }
    adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
    System.out.println("onpostexecute");
    new MyLongTask().execute();
}
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are binding the ArrayList 'valores' to the listview adapter. After you finish downloading the new information you want to display in the ListView, in onPostExecute() (on the UI thread) you run

```
valores.clear();
valores = (ArrayList) YOUR_NEW_VALUES;
adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

where YOUR_NEW_VALUES is an arraylist you created from new yahoo finance information in your long task